# Input function does not accept ?? modifier when used in where= dataset option

Tags: sas

I have the following statement within my proc print:

```
    where ZBTESTCD = 'NEOPSTYP' and missing(input(zbdtc,??e8601dt.));
```

And the SAS issues an error when I run it:

```
ERROR: Syntax error while parsing WHERE clause.
ERROR 22-322: Expecting a format name.  
ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.
```

This very same condition `missing(input(zbdtc,??e8601dt.))` works fine when used within `if` in a datastep.

Is this documented behavior? Any better workaround than having a datastep preceding proc call?

Comment: Would you paste the full head of the data statement. The syntax is different depending on if it is in **SET** statement or independent.

Comment: @pinegulf Why do you say that?  (Other than being `where=(...)` anyway, if that's what you mean, but that would be a different error.)

Comment: @Joe I say that because I wanted to see the full code. And no, I do not remember all error codes by heart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double `??` is used to suppress the setting of `_ERROR_` in a data step. So it would have no meaning in a WHERE clause, especially one used in a PROC instead of a DATA step.

Just use a single `?`.

> ? or ??
>
> specifies the optional question mark (?) and double question
>   mark (??) modifiers that suppress the printing of both the error
>   messages and the input lines when invalid data values are read. The ?
>   modifier suppresses the invalid data message. The ?? modifier also
>   suppresses the invalid data message and, in addition, prevents the
>   automatic variable _ERROR_ from being set to 1 when invalid data are
>   read.